# Problem while running the flutter program

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

While running visual studio code for a flutter program, I am getting this error log in the terminal tab.

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks

```
flutter run -d chrome
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             26.1s
Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome.
This can happen if the websocket connection used by the web tooling is unable to correctly establish a connection, for example due to a firewall.
```

Comment: What operating system you are using? Did you checked your firewall as the message points to?

Answer (score 0):

Try running in release mode.

```
flutter run -d chrome --release
```

Comment: This worked for only one time. But, whenever I execute the program again then, I get the same error in the terminal.